# How to create a button (calling JS code) in a work item configuration?

Tags: xml, tfs

I'd like to add a clickable button to the XML definition of a work item. Currently, the (interesting part of the) work item definition is:

```xml
<Section>
    <Group Label="*****">
        <Control Label="*****" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="*****" />
        <Control Label="*****" Type="LabelControl">
            <Link UrlRoot="http://*****.html" />
        </Control>
    </Group>
</Section>
```

I managed to create a button using `Type="WebpageControl"`:

```xml
<Control Type="WebpageControl">
    <WebpageControlOptions>
        <Content> 
            <![CDATA[<button><a target="_blank" onclick="console.log('test');"><b>Testt</b></a></button>]]>
        </Content> 
    </WebpageControlOptions> 
</Control>
```

However, I can't use `Type="WebpageControl"` in a `Group` containing other `Controls`. Is there a way to have my button directly in the same `Group` as the other `Controls`? I also tried using `Type="LabelControl"` but I failed to call JS with it. Otherwise, is there a workaround ?

Comment: You would write an extension. What you are trying to do **will not** work; you can't embed JavaScript in work item type definitions. Earlier versions of TFS have a different extension model or simply don't support extensions at all, so knowing what version you're using would be useful.

Comment: Sorry I forget it, I am using TFS2018. I will check extensions thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel Mann, I looked for an extension, and used [Work Item REST Request Button](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Apodemus.RESTRequestButton), with which I was able to define a button like this:

```
<ControlContribution Label="*****" Id="Apodemus.RESTRequestButton.RESTRequestButton">
    <Inputs>
        <Input Id="ButtonTitle" Value="*****" />
        <Input Id="Fields" Value="System.Title, System.AssignedTo" />
        <Input Id="Endpoint" Value="https://*****.com:*****/my/api" />
        <Input Id="SendUser" Value="true" />
        <Input Id="ShowResponseBody" Value="true" />
        <Input Id="Method" Value="POST" />
    </Inputs>
</ControlContribution>
```